# Given the coordinates of four points on a plane, how can one determine the shape they form?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, triangles, quadrilateral

Actually it is an algorithm problem, however I cannot solve the problem. So, We have 4 points, how can we know what kind of shape(figure) can be drawn ? I want to learn mathematically. If possible i wonder formulas with four points. There are some examples

```
1.0 1.0
2.0 1.0
3.0 1.0
5.5 5.0
Your points can construct:
A triangle

1.0 1.0
2.0 1.0
3.0 1.0
5.5 1.0
Your points can construct:
A line

1.0 1.0
2.0 1.0
3.0 6.0
5.5 5.0
Your points can construct:
A quadrilateral
```

Comment: I don't agree with the votes to close. Looks like a good question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $4$ points $(x_1,y_1), \ldots, (x_4,y_4)$, then there are $3$ possible answers:

- **quadrilateral** (there are no triplet of points on one line);
- **triangle** ($3$ of points are on one line, and other one $-$ out of line);
- **line** (all $4$ points are on one line).

To check if some $3$ points $(x_1,y_1), ~ (x_2,y_2), ~ (x_3,y_3)$ are on one line (are [collinear](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html)), one can build this value:

$$
C_{123} = 
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right| \tag{1}
$$

and apply test: if $C_{123}=0$, then points are collinear, if $C_{123}\ne 0$, then no.

This way you'll need to check $4$ values: $C_{123}$, $C_{124}$, $C_{134}$, $C_{234}$.

Sometimes your calculations can be terminated earlier: 
if you'll find one zero and one (or more) non-zero values, then it is **triangle**;
if you'll find two zero values, then it is **line** (other values must be zero too).

---

Expression in $(1)$ is [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant), and here is formula for it:

$$
C_{123} = ... = x_1y_2 + x_2y_3+x_3y_1 - x_1y_3-x_2y_1-x_3y_2 \\
= x_1(y_2-y_3) + x_2(y_3-y_1)+x_3(y_1-y_2).
$$

Comment: thank you really thank you

Comment: Why not get more specific? If the midpoints of the two diagonals of the quadrilateral are the same then we have a parallelogram. What about the rest of the types of quadrilaterals?

Comment: @NikeDattani: To find midpoints of diagonals, we have to determine first, which vertices of the quadrilateral are opposite ones (the vertices could be listed in any order). But if the vertices are listed clockwise or counterclockwise, then yes, midpoints of two diagonals is good test for parallelogram.